# Mostrar totales de tabla en php por cada usuario

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy generando un reporte en php que muestra todos los servicios que realizó el movil(conductor) durante el transcurso del mes, a cada servicio se le aplica un porcentaje y se paga una comisión al recepcionista. Logro sacar el total de la tabla pero necesito sacar un reporte por cada conductor.

**Imagen de ejemplo: (así lo debo generar al final de la tabla principal)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos son traídos desde una base de datos y los imprimo mediante un `while` para ir sumando los valores y mostrar un total al final de la tabla principal:

**Imagen de tabla principal:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código PHP con el cual recorro la consulta es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    $total = 0;
        $recp = 0;
        $movil = 0;
        $emp = 0;
        $totalf = 0;

    while($row = $hist->unbuffered_row()):

    if ($row->tipoPago == 'USD' AND $row->tarifa < 100) {
        $row->tarifa = $row->tarifa * 600 .' (USD'.$row->tarifa.')';
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row->fecha ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->hora ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->pasajero ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->destino ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->hab ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->tipoPago ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->nfolio ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->nvale ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->tarifa ?></td>
        <td><?php 

                if ($row->tarifa >= 2000 && $row->tarifa <= 7900) {
                    $can = 500;
                    echo $can;
                }elseif ($row->tarifa >= 8000 && $row->tarifa <= 14900) {
                    $can = 1000;
                    echo $can;
                }elseif ($row->tarifa >= 15000 && $row->tarifa <= 24900) {
                    $can = 2000;
                    echo $can;
                }elseif ($row->tarifa >= 25000 && $row->tarifa <= 59900) {
                    $can = 3000;
                    echo $can;
                }elseif ($row->tarifa >= 60000 && $row->tarifa <= 100000) {
                    $can = 5000;
                    echo $can;
                }elseif ($row->tarifa >= 101000 && $row->tarifa <= 200000){
                    $can = 10000;
                    echo $can;
                }
            ?></td>
        <td class="celda"><?= $res = $row->tarifa - $can ?></td>
        <td class="celda"><?= $men =  $res * ($row->porcentaje/100)  ?></td>
        <td class="celda"><?= $final = ($res - $men) ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->movil ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->recep ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->recepDesp ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->comentario ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
                $total += $row->tarifa;
                $recp += $can;
                $movil += $res;
                $emp += $men;
                $totalf += $final;

        ?>
    <?php endwhile?>
    <tr>
            <th colspan="8">Totales</th>
            <td><?= $total ?></td>
            <td><?= $recp ?></td>
            <td><?= $movil ?></td>
            <td><?= $emp ?></td>
            <td><?= $totalf ?></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Aún no logro definir como ir guardando los totales por cada conductor para mostrar la tabla resumida(imagen1), de antemano agradezco cualquier sugerencia o ayuda.

Comment: Puedes colocar los datos como un archivo csv?, ésto lo puedes lograr directamente desde la base de datos ya SQL tiene funciones de agregación que es lo que tu quieres hacer. select sum(campo) from table; https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Fundamentos-de-SQL-Agrupaciones-y-funciones-de-agregacion.aspx

Comment: @zerocool no entendí muy bien su comentario

Comment: Bueno para ayudarte debes hacer que tu problema sea facil de replicar, esto es colocar la data de ejemplo en un archivo que se pueda copiar, no una imagen, así quien quiera probar hacer una consulta o resolver el problema no se vea desanimado por el hecho de tener que pasar mucho tiempo cuadrando un caso de prueba. Te propongo también el usar sqlfiddle y que nos dejes el link de la base de datos creada con los datos. Por otra lo que te comentaba es que lo que haces en el script para manipular los datos lo puedes hacer directamente desde el query, $can puede ser un campo de la consulta y ya.

Comment: En la base de datos eso se hace con un case, al igual que el calculo de la tarifa por 600, también se puede hacer esa operación en la consulta, de nuevo, cuadrar un caso de uso para ésto es una tarea un poco tediosa y de seguro por ello no ha generado mucho interes en la comunidad de responderla. Saludos!

Comment: Entendido, haré la base de datos en sqlfidle y la subiré

Answer (score 0):

Si el contenido lo tienes en una base de datos haciendo una consulta sql con un grup by por nombre y aplicando un SUM en el select diciendo que campo quieres sumar, obtendrás el total de cada usuario en un campo

En caso que no, tendrás de crear un array donde los identificadores de fila sea el nombre, y yendo comprobando si el siguiente nombre lo tienes o no vas incluyéndolo al array o sumándolo al valor que ya tiene.

Otra solución seria utilizar facilidades que contienen algunos framworks como Laravel, que son las colecciones, las cuales se pueden convertir de arrays y jsons y puedes hacer distintas modificaciones como grups by, order bys, eliminar repetidos [etc..](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods)

En fin no se si te servirá de ayuda pero es lo que haría yo

Comment: Hola Edu, en este caso necesito empezar a sumar tras unas operaciones realizadas durante un while en la vista.